# Regex to automate some html tagging

Tags: php, regex

I'm having 800 entries that are very similar, but they need some stuff done to them.
The format is like this:

`<td class="description">

    Describing text.

    Might very well be 2 paragraphs

</td>`

I need to do some stuff to the text inside the cell.
I've tried to use preg_replace('/(.+)</td>/'). It ends up with two problems.

1. I don't manage to fetch what's
   inside the parenthesis, but it will
   also fetch the cell tags.
2. It will fetch everything until the last 
   `</td>` in the document. I just want
   it to go to the first occurrence of
   `</td>`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want [DOM for this, not Regex](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Change+content+of+DOM+node+php)

Comment: Don't mix HTML and Regex! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 1):

First of all, .+ will grab everything... it won't just start at `<td>`. You will want to add a regex to pull the beginning of the table col:

```
<td[^>]*?>
```

(note, `[^>]*` means match non-`>` characters until we find one.)

Also, `.+` and `.*` are *greedy*, meaning that it will grab as much as possible. To change this behavior, add a `?` after it, like such: `.+?`. This makes it satisfy only as much as it needs to.

So, you will have

```
<td[^>]*)>(.*?)<\/td>
```

This was a lesson on regex, but I really think you shouldn't be using regex for this. Regex can break pretty easily once you start having nested tables or anything more complicated than simple html.

Answer (score 1):

[**D̨͙̯̹̼ỏ͇̥̱͚̲͖̣͢ǹ̶̥͉̳͈͈̏̉ͧ'ͧͬ͏̪̩͓̳̬̱ͅt͇̝̖ͦ̏̏̍̉͠ ͙̺̹͚͎̐̒ͥ͑̀ṷ͍̖͕̐ͫ̚s̤͖͇̲̪͊͋̉ͨͪ̚e͚̲͎͓̟͊̍ ̲̬̩͇̗̭̌̊̑̊͝r̷̦͔̞̜̬ͦe̔̓͒͊̌g̹̘̬̭ͨ̐̽̐̂u̼̹̔ͣ͑͐̓͋l͈̤̘͉̰̏͌̚a̵̤̞̥̋rͭ ̦̝͓̟̣̯̄́̎̀̔ͥe̢̟̥̹̊̅̌̅̋x̠̠̲͚̝͋ͪp̧̽̉ṟ͉̏͌̊̐ͅe͖͎̞͇̽͛̀s͓͈̒s̴͚̮̹ͧ̽i̐ͪ̈́̏̑o͇͓̎n͎̐̃ͨ͢s̜͉̼̹͇̐ͥ̏̈́̽̔͐ ̛̑ͧf̩̋ͨ͑ö̮̗̩́̏̀ͩ̆r̮͓͊̌ ̸̪͈̫̬̭̻̮͊ͧ͂ͬ̌H͎̤̟͙̞ͪ͐̃̿ͮͭͅT͚̉͑͛̉M̴̦͖͇͔͚̙ͭͭ̽L͗ͦ̋̓͑ ͍͈͙̞͍̻̉̆͆̃͘p̓̉̃͆͛ͦ́͟r͕͙ͭͭͦ͡ő̹͍̳̳ͯ̐c̵̙͇͋̅è͖̘̲̰͉͉̺͛́ͪͩ̋͜s̾͑ͬͬ͐̋̀s̜̼̰̞̺͗ͫ̒ͫͧͥͅḭ̪ͫ͋ͫ̚n̿͐҉̺̩̟̻̳g͑̀̑̆̈̾!̠̓ͭ̈͜**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

If you still want to try it ... use non-capturing groups `(?:)` to exclude the tags and a lazy quantifier `*?` to match only up to the first closing tag.

```
(?:<td[^>]*>).*?(?:</td>)
```

This requires dot-all mode and may still fail if for example the description attribute contains a closing angle bracket.

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain that there is no HTML in the table cells, the following non-regex code may help:

```
// $entries contains all of the table cell entries.
$newentries = "";
$cells = split("</td>",$entries);
while (list(,$data) = each($cells)) {
    $newentries .= "<td class=\"description\">";
    $text = substr($data,strpos($data, ">") + 1);
    // perform modifications on $text
    // i.e. $text = "<B>" . $text . "</B>";
    $newentries .= $text;
    $newentries .= "</td>";
}

// $newentries now contains the modified cell entries.
```

This probably isn't 100% what you're looking for, but maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

You may use:

```
preg_replace(
  '/<td (.*?)>(.*?)<\/td>/sm',
  '<td class="description"><strong>$2</strong></td>',
  $data
)
```

If what you are trying to do with the text inside is complicate, use a callback function.

Answer (score 0):

As all the other ones have said: RegExp is bad, at least here!

So, basic Regex is

```
#<td[^>]*>(.*?)</td>#s
```

(Note I used the s-Modifier, otherwise the RegExp wouldn't work.)

Now, this RegExp is wrong, even though it may be okay for your purposes. To be more strict you have to know, that `>` is allowed in attributes. Therefore this Regex may break things.

```
#<td(\s+\w+="[^"]+")\s*>(.*?)</td>#s
```

I think this now will be quite secure if you're dealing with XML. But sure, it may break on rare occasions, which I right now can't think off.

Answer (score 0):

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML($htmlstring);
$x = new DOMXPath($d);
$tds = $x->query("//td[@class='description']//text()");
for($i = 1; $i <= $tds->length; $i++){
    $tds->item($i)->replaceData(0,mb_strlen($tds->item($i)->wholeText),strtoupper($tds->item($i)->wholeText));   
}
var_dump($d->saveHTML());
```